# How do I extract data from jQuery sortable with several list linked with connectedWith?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

### Problem

My scenario is that on a page, I have several lists, which I have made sortable using jQueryUI .sortable. For example, I have a page showing various teams, and under each team, I display a list of team members. Using .sortable, I want to be able to drag the members between the teams, and then have this change saved in my backend MySQL DB. I also didn't want to use `<ul>` & `<li>` but as .sortable() can be applied to other tags, this shouldn't be a problem. Using .sortable's `serialize` or `toArray` methods, gives you one big list containing all the members, with no indication as to which team they now belong to.

I found a couple of examples on StackOverflow which alluded to how this might be achieved, but one I couldn't get to work at all, and the other required me to know all the team names in advance. As I want the teams to be generated dynamically this solution wasn't practical.

I figured it out in the end and am posting my solution on here in case it helps others in the future.

Comment: The question is nigh-incomprehensible by itself. I had to read through your answer to even begin to understand your problem. It's more readable to post most of the code or a fiddle in the question, and have **just the solution** in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    var team_update = function(e) {
        $('.sortable-items').each(function(){
            var team_id = $( this ).attr("id");

            var data =  {
                tid: team_id,
                users: $('#' + team_id).sortable('toArray')
            };
            console.log(data);

            $.post('update_sql.php', data);

            });

        });
    }

    $( ".sortable-items" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".sortable-items",
        items: ".sortable-item",
        helper: "clone",
        stop : team_update
    })
        .disableSelection();


});
```

#### Explanation

The 'clever' bit is in the team_update object, which gets called by the 'stop' attribute of .sortable().

I have applied a class of `.sortable_items` to every team container on the page, and a class of `.sortable_item` to every team member. These have then been defined as parameters in the .sortable() function.

When the stop event fires on the .sortable() function, it calls the team_update function. This then uses a jQuery selector `$('.sortable_items')` to create a jQuery object containing all the 'teams'. I then use the .each() function to find the div's ID, which I've made the same as the team name, and then build a javascript array containing the members of that team.

The resulting output is a multidimensional JSON object, depicting each team it found on the page, and its members. It then becomes relatively simple to send this to a php script to parse through and update each team.

Comment: looks like you've already have the answer before posting the question? interesting.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: it's just private/personal idea. Normally asking something should be a problematic thing ***to the asker*** first. I think SO should allows user to create some kind of ***article***, then you can write your own article.

Comment: I know the asker can give his own answer but this is the first time I've seen the answer was posted right after asking (nearly at the same time).

Comment: The common way to approach the problem is to put the team in a custom html/jquery attribute, that you can then use as a filter, eg. `$(".player[data-team='" + team + "']")` instead of looping over all items with `.each()`. The `.each()` solution might actually be faster, though.